# abstractlist protobuf java

Tags: java, list, protocol-buffers

I have an object containing a list sent from a C# client to a Java server. The serialization with protobuf work perfectly and the object is received perfectly in Java. But the class generated with protoc.exe (can we call it a proto class?) have a list that i can't modify. Basically, I have to add some values in it before returning it to C#, but when I try to add a value, i have an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    ...
```

Here's how i'm adding values:

```
MyProtoObject.MyResult result = MyProtoObject.MyResut.NewBuilder()
        .setId(1)
        .setValue(9.135)
        .build();
MyObject.getResultList().add(result);
```

How can i insert values in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after regenerating the proto class, it appears some methods was missing (I probably made mistakes in first generation). So now i can add values in the list :

```
MyObjectProto.MyObject o = MyObjectProto.MyObject.newBuilder()
    .addAllResults(listOfCalculations)
    .build();
```

listOfCalculation is a List of results objects

or just :

```
MyObjectProto.MyObject o = MyObjectProto.MyObject.newBuilder()
    .addResult(calculationResult)
    .build();
```

CalculationResult is a single result object

Thanks to Flavio

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's somewhat of a workaround, but you could try this:

```
List<MyResult> l = new ArrayList<MyResult>(MyObject.getResultList());
l.add(result);
MyObject.setResultList(l);
```

Comment: the setters of a proto class are specifics and use the builder like this `MyObject.toBuilder().setResult(index, value).build();` Unfortunately, there isn't setter with a list parameter (only with int index and double value)

Comment: Is there a `MyObject.toBuilder().addAllResult(l)` method?

Comment: only `myObject.getResult().add(value)`. The getResult() return the list. But add() method return the same exception (abstractList...)